Как добавить в программу Windows Froms .Net свой шрифт?
Хочу добавить свой шрифт, чтобы даже те, у кого его нету, могли видеть в моей программе встроенный шрифт

В документации вроде есть то, что вам нужно (пункт: How to: Create a Private Font Collection).
